# Runnig a AutoHotKey script failed

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I can run below script in SciTE4AotuHotKey:

```
CapsLock::Send, {CTRLDOWN}{SHIFTDOWN}{SHIFTUP}{CTRLUP}{CTRLUP}
    return
!^CapsLock::CapsLock

CapsLock & j:: Send  {Down}
CapsLock & k:: Send {Up}
CapsLock & h:: Send {Left}
CapsLock & l:: Send {right}
CapsLock & p:: Send {PGUP}
CapsLock & ə:: Send {PGDN}
CapsLock & a:: Send {home}
CapsLock & e:: Send {end}
```

But when I save it to a file and double click on it, following error appears:

[image]

What is the problem?

I am using AutoHotKey_L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this could happen if you have more than one version of Autohotkey installed, and Scite4Autohotkey is running the version with Unicode support, while double-clicking on the file is running the version without unicode support? Try looking for multiple versions of Autohotkey installed. Or try running the script from command line pointing to your Autohotkey_L installation and see if it works that way.

Answer (score 1):

The character you are using with <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> on Line 12 is not a valid character.

Comment: I see that in the error dialog!!!, as mentioned in the question the code can be run from SciTE4AotuHotKey, indeed the script currently is running on my PC.

Comment: In my keyboard layout `ə` is placed in `;` posision.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works, but you could try:

```
CapsLock & sc027::
```

SC027 is the scancode for ; on my Keyboard